# How to find N's complement of a number?

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation

I want to find 9's complement of number but failed.

I tried it with the methods of 1's and 2's complements but no effect.

What is common method to find out the N's complement of a number?

Comment: take one example , 9's complement of 45 (in decimal)

Comment: Have you looked here? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_complements

Comment: yes yes, but it'll not satisfy my requirement here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The nines' complement in base 10 is found by subtracting each digit from 9.

So 45 (= ...000045) becomes 54 (= ...999954).

Ten's complement is just nines' complement plus 1. So ...000045 becomes (...999954 + 1) = ...999955.

More info on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_complements).

Comment: Thats fine ..but ,

what is the 53's complement of 200(binary) --- (51)(53)(53)--what is this?

Comment: How can 200 be binary? Binary has only 0 and 1 digits.

Comment: sorry , i mean its decimal...200(decimal)

Comment: @Renjith: 200 decimal in base 53 is: (3)(41), so the 52s' complement is (49)(11) and the 53's complement is one more, i.e. (49)(12).

Comment: Note there are only two radix complements in any base: the radix complement and the diminished radix complement. To ask for the 53's complement in base 10 is a meaningless question.

Comment: @Renjith: In base n, there are only two complements: ns' complement and (n-1)'s complement. So in decimal there are only two meaningful things you can ask for: 9s' complement or 10's complement.

Comment: @Renjith:  Binary has only 1's-complement and 2's-complement; base-10 has only 9's-complement and 10's-complement.  "53's-complement" only makes sense if you are working in base-53 or base-54 (the two cases have different meanings and will give different answers).  As far as I'm aware, complements are only used in computing, so the only ones that are really important in the real-world are the two complements used in binary (and occasionally the decimal-complements, if you're writing code that uses BCD numbers http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal)

Comment: Thanks. But Can you explain the real use of 1's and 2's complements in  real computing, with one example?

/renjithg

Comment: @Renjith: An actual usage of this is to represent negative numbers. For example -1 can be represented by ...11110 if using the 1s' complement system. and .....11111 with 2's complement. Most modern systems use 2's complement. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations for more info.

Answer (score 8):

`n`'s complement use: (simple three step method).

Suppose `512 - 96 = ?` (both numbers are given in base n, say base:14).

1. Find `n-1` complement of `96` (second number which is to be subtracted). 
   `13`'s complement of `099` is `DDD - 096 = D47` (since A=10, B=11, C=12, D=13).
2. Find `n`'s complement by adding `1` to `n - 1`'s complement value. `14`'s complement is `D47 + 1 = D48`.
3. Add the first number (`512`) with the `n`'s complement (`D48`) and leave the carry. `512 + D48 = 45A` (carry `1` removed).

CHECK:

```
512(14 base) = 996(10 base)
96(14 base) = 132(10 base)
996-132 = 864(base 10) = 45A(base 14) HENCE CHECKED.
```